# Use azure-sdk-for-java to build the docker image

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-for-java, azure-acr

The az acr CLI provides the functionality to build (and push) the docker image with [az acr build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-build).

Does the java sdk give the same option? If so, would you know of any sample?

I've tried finding more info on the sdk's github and microsoft docs, but no luck so far.

Comment: There seems to be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.containerregistry.dockerbuildrequest?view=azure-java-stable
I'll check how it'd work and update on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are relevant samples in the sdk github generated samples: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/2d1d4e228f6d1145f460ab61398ca25d9bd8f96c/sdk/resourcemanager/azure-resourcemanager/src/samples/java/com/azure/resourcemanager/containerregistry/generated/RegistriesScheduleRunSamples.java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).